# How to construct a fixed-size graphical marker?

Tags: graphics

I would like to have graphical markers available that I can later insert into graphics to mark certain points. I would like those markers to appear at a fixed size (ideally given in terms of font sizes, so if I give a size of "12", say, the marker is the size of a capital letter in a 12-point font).
What I have at this point is this:

```
cmg = Graphics[{FaceForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi/2}],
    FaceForm[LightGray], Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, Pi}], FaceForm[Black],
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi, 3 Pi/2}], FaceForm[LightGray], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {3 Pi/2, 2 Pi}]}];
cmarker[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}, r_?NumericQ] = 
  Graphics[Inset[cmg, {x, y}, {0, 0}, r], ImageSize -> 50];
```

Now I do

```
g1 = {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Opacity[0.3], Darker[Pink], 
     Rectangle[{-1, -3/4}, {1, 3/4}]}, ImageSize -> 150], 
   cmarker[{0, 0}, 0.5], 
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{0, 0}]}]};
g2 = {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Opacity[0.3], Darker[Pink], 
     Rectangle[{-1, -3/4}, {1, 3/4}]}, ImageSize -> 250], 
   cmarker[{0, 0}, 0.5], 
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{0, 0}]}]};
Row[{Show[g1], Show[g2]}]
```

I get

[image]

So, (apart from the minor issue of rescaling to font size; that's easy to solve), my problem is that the markers do change size. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the graphics directly, you can use Magnify to change the size.

Example.

```
cmg = Graphics[{FaceForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi/2}], 
    FaceForm[LightGray], Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, Pi}], FaceForm[Black],
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi, 3 Pi/2}], FaceForm[LightGray], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {3 Pi/2, 2 Pi}]}];
Multicolumn[
 ListPlot[RandomInteger[10, 5], PlotMarkers -> Magnify[cmg, 0.1], 
    ImageSize -> #] & /@ {100, 200, 300, 400}, {2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hah, that's it, thanks!